# resources fail to load - internal server error

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

My application doesn't load any of the javascript and css resources. Everything was fine and then this happened all of a sudden. I have no clue what might be causing this. I don't know what part of the code I should include so here's the screen shot:

[image]

The application is based on Asp.net webforms

Comment: check server's error.log

Comment: @SiCK how do I do that?

Comment: @laszlokiss88 You can see error message in the developer log which says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Do you have any http modules running? If the application pool managed pipeline mode changed from "Classic" to "Integrated", requests for js or css files will also hit the http module which could be the cause. Otherwise it is not normal for the web server to return with a 500 internal server error for resources.

Comment: If you are running the project through visual studio, just start debugging, and go to DEBUG / Exceptions menu and tick "Thrown" check box next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions. This will cause the debugger to catch any errors even ifthey are handled by a catch block.

Comment: If an exception is not handled and the server returns http 500, you should see the details of the error in the aplication event log (Start-Run-eventvwr (enter))

Comment: Thank you @OguzOzgul I just found the error. I allowed static content in web.config file which was causing this.

Comment: You can also switch to the Network tab in Chrome developer tools (or whatever browser it is) to see the response body for the HTTP 500 errors. The response may contain more details about the exception

Comment: "I allowed static content in web.config file which was causing this." Could you expand on this, in case other people encounter the same error and are unsure what to check.

Comment: The static content element configures several settings related to processing requests for static files in IIS. I was including mimetype static content in order to play html5 video on the web server.  IIS will not return file types that are not added to the staticontent element or that have mappings in the handlers element by default. This behavior prevents unauthorized access to files that do not have mappings in the IIS configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused due to static content being allowed in the web.config file. I commented out this line :

```
    <staticContent>
  <!--<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />-->
</staticContent>
```